# Laravel 8 Cpanel Deploy - 404 Errors

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

I am trying to deploy my Laravel 8 app to a folder in CPANEL (first time I've deployed Laravel). I have searched the forum and made changes as the many posts direct. I am getting 404 errors across all pages apart from the homepage and login and register pages. This is a common error but I cant find a solution. Dont shoot me.

1.All files uploaded to url/laravel/blog

1. Public folder moved outside and renamed public_html
2. The /laravel folder now has two directories /blog and /public_html
3. index.php in the public_html folder updated:

require **DIR**.'/../blog/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once **DIR**.'/../blog/bootstrap/app.php';

4. New .htaccess file added to the root of the public_html and set to chmod 755 (detailed below)
5. Renamed the cache folder in the /bootstrap folder so that new cache is created (I hope)
6. Database is linked within the .env file

I am out of ideas, I have created a test html file in the public folder and I can see this in the browser when I navigate to it. I am learning and any help will be appreciated.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: "Public folder moved outside and renamed public_html" what exactly do you mean by this? Did you move and rename the 'public' folder from within the laravel application? The laravel application would not know how to navigate such a change.

Comment: Advice I have seen, says to move the public folder outside of the laravel folder to the server root folder and rename it to public_html. I have tried to leave the public folder in the laravel folder as it is after install and I still get the same 404 issues.

Comment: The laravel application expects the folder and file structure as provided. Moving things around like this will break it. You will need to put this back as it was originally and address the problems in the .htaccess file.

Comment: Thanks James, this makes sense to me. Numerous posts say to move these folders. Can you offer any advice on the Htaccess. Every link on the homepage moves the route one step back so instead of /blog/public/1 it goes to: blog/1

Comment: You need to point the webserver's root directory to the public directory within the laravel application folder.

Comment: James, that worked. Thanks for your help. Cant believe its thats simple ad the acres of guides for deployment are creating more issues.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to point the subdomain/add-on domain to the public folder. No need to move anything or change Htaccess etc.... Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/users/2325620/james-clark-developer

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^$ public/index.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: What is "this"? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Thanks for responding, but with the in place the homepage now 404 errors. Any other advice?